# Как посмотреть текущий вывод задачи, которую выполняет cron?

Tags: linux, bash, логирование, cron, echo

Необходимо добавить в cron задачу, которая будет выполнять скрипт, содержащий большое кол-во выводов в stdout. При этом нужно реализовать две такие штуки:

1. Выводы в stdout скрипта должны писаться в файл (в том числе ошибка с которой вываливается скрипт). При этом этот log файл каждый раз перед выполнением задачи должен очищаться. Т.е. содержать в себе log только последней выполненной задачи.
2. Должна быть возможность посмотреть текущие выводы в stdout выполняющейся в данной момент задачи. Задач в один момент, конечно же, может быть несколько. И выполняются они все на удаленном сервере. И вот надо иметь возможность подключиться к серверу, посмотреть какие задачи выполняются в данный момент. И прям в live-режиме хочется увидеть текущий stdout выполняющейся в данный момент задачи.

Comment: Добавить в команду крона вконце  > /var/log/tut_imya_loga.log 2>&1 и смотреть его через `tail -f` - не вариант?

Comment: @nobody похоже `tail` то, что надо. Спасибо. А  `> /var/log/tut_imya_loga.log 2>&1` будет каждый раз заново перезаписывать файл или в конец писать?

Comment: Я одного не пойму - а почему нельзя в этих задачах использовать нормальный вывод в *syslog* ? Тогда бы все проблеммы были сразу решены. Или исходные тексты задачи отсутствуют?

В том варианте, что предложил *nobody*, если запущено несколько задач, то они буду затирать выдачу друг друга.

Comment: @Sergey может и можно) Просто не шибко ориентируюсь в linux, поэтому и спрашиваю. Спасибо за мысль, проштудирую тему.

Comment: @Sergey так в разные log-файлы писаться-то будет.

Comment: @Sergey исходники есть. Это php с выводом в виде echo. Я так понимаю, идея с syslog предополагает заменить все echo на syslog()? Или можно как-то перенаправить в описание задачи в crontab? И чем потом просматривать в "live-режиме"? Тем же tail?

Comment: @leaf **так в разные log-файлы писаться-то будет.** Нет. Хотя в Linux существует несколько (совсем немного) разных log-файлов, но все они узкоспециализированы. Вы можете попытаться настроить параметры лога для Вашей задачи (вплоть до того, что лог будет по FTP передаваться на какой-то другой сервер), но если ничего не делать, то вывод пойдёт в один файл. Каждая запись в лог-файле сопровождается временной меткой, pid процесса и специальной меткой, которую Вы задаёте при вызове *openlog()*. Эта метка позволит Вам быстро отфильтровать(с помощью grep) только Ваши сообщения.

Comment: @leaf **идея с syslog предополагает заменить все echo на syslog()?** совершенно верно. Можно даже поднапрячься и написать макрос :-)  **просматривать в "live-режиме"? Тем же tail?** - разумеется. Лично я, при отладке, делаю так: *tail -f /var/log/messages | grep svl &*

Внимание: *svl* - это идентификатор, который я указал в *openlog()*. Амперсенд в конце командной строки уводит эту команду в фон и я могу дальше работать в терминале любым образом. А интересующие меня сообщения будут выведены на терминал, только когда они появляются реально.